# New chat welcome message "OK" button is invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

The message that now appears the first time you join a chat room (for a given site, it appears?) looks odd on M&TV's chat. Specifically, the "OK I'll keep it in mind" button isn't visible until you hover.

For reference here are the pop-ups from three different chat rooms: the C# room on SO, The h Bar on SE, and The Screening Room on SE:

[image: C# chat room popup]

***The C# Chat room***

---

[image: Physics chat room popup]

***The h Bar***

---

[image: Movies & TV chat room popup]

***The Screening Room***

---

As you can see, there's a big blank space where the button should be for M&TV, but if I hover over where the button should be, you can just barely make it out:

[image: Movies & TV chat room popup with hover]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks, fixed now. The movies.se theme has extra styling for buttons in the bottom area, and those extra styles were incorrectly applied here as well.

Comment: Mind looking at http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1652 ?